# JavaScript: Math.random: How to choose a random number between 190 and 255 "unevenly", not "evenly"?

Tags: javascript, random

If you want to choose a random number between 190 and 255, expecting *evenly* distributed results, the code you need is as simple as the following, correct?

`190 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 66);`

But what if you prefer *unevenly* distributed results between 190 and 255? I mean, for instance, the closer a number is to the lower end of the range (i.e. 190), the higher the possibility of the number being chosen.

Let us suppose that the code returns a random number:

- `between 190 and 210 with a 70% probability.`
- `between 211 and 230 with a 20% probability.`
- `between 231 and 255 with a 10% probability.`

I think that the uneven distribution like this adds an interesting flavour to the act of choosing a random number.

I've written the code for this in two different ways, the second one taking a more complex form. I started to learn programming just several days ago, so I've written them, drawing on what little I know of JavaScript at the moment. I wonder if I can express them more efficiently.

Incidentally, I have one specific question in mind:

In the `1st Code`, do I need to place `var` in front of `attackPoint = midRange` and `attackPoint = highRange` in the `if/else` statement?

**1st Code:**

```
var lowRange = 190 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
var midRange = 211 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
var highRange = 231 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);

var randomHundred = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

if (randomHundred <= 70) {
    var attackPoint = lowRange;
}
else if (randomHundred <= 90) {
    var attackPoint = midRange;
}
else {
    var attackPoint = highRange;
}

console.log(attackPoint);
```

**2nd Code:**

```
var lowRange = 190 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
var midRange = 211 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
var highRange = 231 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);

var emptyArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i < 70) {
        emptyArray.push(lowRange);
    }
    else if (i < 90) {
        emptyArray.push(midRange);
    }
    else {
        emptyArray.push(highRange);
    }
};

var attackPoint = emptyArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)];

console.log(attackPoint);
```

Comment: you are correct that you will need to initalize `attackPoint` outside of the if/else statement, as it is out of scope otherwise

Answer (score 3):

The 1st way improvement:

You don't need to calculate random values for **all** ranges, you only need the **selected range**. Also it's unnecessary to cast `0..1` range to `0..100`. You can deal with `0..1` range directly.

```
var q = Math.random(), attackPoint;

if (q < 0.7) {
    attackPoint = 190 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
}
else if (q < 0.9) {
    attackPoint = 211 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
}
else {
    attackPoint = 231 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
}

console.log(attackPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your specific point, I am not a Javascript expert, but I think you need:

```
var attackPoint;  // Declare, but do no initialize the variable.
if (randomHundred <= 70) {
    attackPoint = lowRange;
}
else if (randomHundred <= 90) {
    attackPoint = midRange;
}
else {
    attackPoint = highRange;
}
```

A more efficient way is going to involve "stretching" the range you want to be more likely, and then choosing randomly.  Something like:

```
var attackValues = []
for (var i = 190; i < 211; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        attackValue.push(i);  // Seven values here.
    }
}
for (var i = 211; i < 231; i++) {
     attackValue.push(i); attackValue.push(i); // Two values here
}
for (var i = 231; i < 256; i++) {
     attackValue.push(i);  // Just one value here.
}

// The attackValue array could be calculated once and stored for repeated
// use if your inflection points stay constant.

var attackPoint = attackValue[ Math.floor(Math.random() * attackValue.length) ]
```

The idea is to fill attackValue array with the possible results, putting in multiple copies of the values you want more often, and then choosing one at random.

Comment: `var attackPoint;  // Declare, but do no initialize the variable.` This is exactly what I was hoping to learn. I didn't know that a variable can be declared without filling the part after `=` (i.e. without initializing, as you put it). I would have written something like `var attackPoint = xxxxx` to give the variable a temporary value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to do something like square the random value, and *then* convert to integer.  Squaring makes smaller values more likely in a somoother way than adding specific inflexion points.  Depending on your application, that may be better (or not).

Answer (score 0):

Just from a programming style it is good form to separate the table of probabilities from the logic that generates the random numbers. The reason being that the exact details of the probabilities and ranges are likely to change over time, but the idea of a weighted random number will stay constant. So once you've got the weighted random number code changing, you don't want to have to change it time and again:

```
var table = [
    { probability:70, low:190, hi: 210},
    { probability:20, low:211, hi: 230},
    { probability:10, low:231, hi: 255}
]

function weightedRandom(table) {
    var total  = table.reduce(function(sum, line) {
        return sum + line.probability;
    }, 0);
    var select = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        var line = table[i];
        select -= table[i].probability;
        if (select < 0) {
            return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (line.hi - line.low)) +
                    line.low;)
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(weightedRandom(table));
}
```

NOTE: you could simplify the above code if you assume that the probabilities will always add to 100.

When I run this I get:

```
237
228
239
209
193
218
213
193
245
214
```

which seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a possible solution too:

```
var number = Math.random();
var index  = Math.floor(number * 66) + 190;   
//answer:
console.log(Math.floor(number * dist(index) * 66) + 190);

function dist(index) {
   var retValue;    
   if (index < 210) {
        retValue = .7;
    }
    else if (number >= 210 && number < 230) {
        retValue = .2;
    }
    else {
        retValue = .1;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```